# Using GridList Component header is getting scroll with mouse scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

While using GridList component my header is getting scroll while scrolling the list, but I want to get it attached with the top of the header where exactly it is.
Like below is getting the header is scrolled while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fixed` as your `position` property for your header component

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```